# Showing html in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I create application for read news, and I get content with server in the form of html code. I use standard WebView control for showing him, but it is not very well. Because this control you cannot change. And I founded [HTMLTextBox](http://msptoolkit.codeplex.com/) but this control does not display youtube video. My question what control is best to use for this?

Comment: remember to check if it work for the same for wp8 and wp8.1, because I had a problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 solutions to display HTML :

- Parse the HTML and display it with your own XAML. You could use the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the html you want.
- Let someone parse the HTML for you and display it with a custom control like the HTMLTextBox you mentioned.
- Let the browser parse the HTML for you and display it with the classic WebView. Note that you can add some css or js to enhance, improve or manage the html.

Comment: Cool, thanks, but maybe there are ready-made, superior controls than webview control?

Comment: When you use the WebView control you call the engine of Internet Explorer. I dont think there is something superior on windows phone. You can browse google for some alternatives, if you find something I will be glad to hear about it.